# Python Pycharm error while installing packages from pypi on Ubuntu

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu, pycharm

I don't know what to do. No package is able to install. I am on Ubuntu if it is of any relevance. First image shows my settings, selected interpreter [image: first image]

Here is what happens when I try to install ("+" above Package) numpy. It is the same for any other package.

[image]

When I click on "Details" I get this command output:

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/274/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 73, in run_pip
    runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 207, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/pestilene/Projects/Python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "/home/pestilene/Projects/Python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/home/pestilene/Projects/Python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/home/pestilene/Projects/Python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/home/pestilene/Projects/Python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "/home/pestilene/Projects/Python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "/home/pestilene/Projects/Python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import getLogger
  File "/home/pestilene/Projects/Python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "/home/pestilene/Projects/Python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version, site_packages, user_site
  File "/home/pestilene/Projects/Python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import _distutils, _sysconfig
  File "/home/pestilene/Projects/Python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'
```

This is what is in my "Manage repositories"

[image]

I also tried installing directly from command line with no luck.

[image]

If anyone has any suggestions on how to solve this issue, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the `python3-distutils` apt package is missing.

You can try installing it with `sudo apt install python3-distutils`

It might be necessary to recreate the venv afterwards. That should be possible through PyCharm.